# Under what condition should we use them and Which method is best to use?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

In the following 2 methods,

1. **Under what situation should we use the 2 methods respectively or when should we use these 2 methods respectively?**
2. **What is the difference between these two methods?**
3. **Which method is best to use?**

Lets say we have 2 contracts suu and foo

**Suu Contract:**

```
contract suu{

    uint public value;

    function sums( uint a,uint b) public view returns(uint){
         uint result=a+b;
       return result;
    }
```

**Foo Contract:**

```
  contract foo {
        // Empty Contract
        //Yet to write a function in this contract
                                                          
     }
```

**Method - 1**

```
contract foo is suu{
    function mul(uint a , uint b ) public view returns(uint){

      uint res=sums(a,b) // sums function Inherited from Suu contract;
      return res*10;

}
```

**Method - 2**

```
import "./Suu.sol"

contract foo {

    Suu suuContract = Suu("CONTRACT_ADDRESS_OF_SUU")
  
  function mul(uint a , uint b ) public view returns(uint){

  uint res=suuContract.sums(a,b); //sums function from suu Contract
     return res*10;

}
```

**In the above 2 methods, it gives the same answer,**

- which method is best to use
- Under what conditions should we use these 2 methods respectively?

Answer (score 0):

In the first method you're using inheritance, you are then telling foo to behave like suu so methods and storage variables from suu will belong to foo as you have written them in foo.

You use this method to divide your code into chunks and it is best practice to not write very long smart contracts to make security auditing much simpler.

In the second method you are calling an already deployed contract (suu) and using one of it's functions. In that case the functions is set to view, but it is possible to write a state changing function and change the state of suu. You are basically calling suu just like you call any other contract directly from your account.

Sometimes you need to call a deployed contract's method (like in Method 2) ( to make a flashloan for example ), instead of importing the whole contract, you just import the interface, which is an abstract contract that includes the method's signature.

Things to note:

- You couldn't have been able to call sums if it was set to external
  instead of public. Public means the the method can be called from an
  EOA or a smart contract.
- In your case, sums can be set to pure instead of view since it
  doesn't read from storage.